# Hex to int32 Big Endian

Tags: python, int32

I am trying to convert this hex to the correct INT32 Big Endian that would be:

```
ffd7c477 --> -2636681
```

I checked how it should look here:

http://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/

I dont know how to convert it. This is where the latitude is

```
payload = "1901000a03010aff01ff01300a01ffd7c4750016c0540322ed"
latitude = payload[28:36] = ffd7c477
```

Here I get the wrong unsigned value:

```
int(binary[28:36], 16)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked `struct.unpack('>i', "ffd7c477".decode('hex'))`

Comment: Nice. I find it easier to convert types in Ruby first `["ffd7c477"].pack('H*').unpack('l>')`. Well, no need to port it to Python now.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python will use the byteorder of your processor architecture by default to handle numbers (you can check your systems byteorder with `sys.byteorder`), you'll have to explicitly specify that you want to treat the given value as big endian. The `struct` module will allow you to do this:

```
import struct, codecs
val = "ffd7c477"
struct.unpack("!i", codecs.decode(val, "hex"))
```

The first argument of `unpack`: `!` means to treat the bytes as big endian, `i` means to treat the bytes as int32 values.